# Prevent Browser Search Hijack

Tags: browser, search, malware, malware-detection, hijack

What is the best way to prevent my browser's default search being hijacked? Also, what is the quickest/easiest way to clean up this sort of hijack?

I just had to clean off all the browsers on my computer because somehow they had thefastestweb.com as default search in the address bar and search bar. I haven't been visiting strange websites or installing random software as this computer is a work computer.

I removed it from my other browsers and left it on IE to see if Malwarebytes would catch something like this but the scan came up clean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Internet Explorer:

1. Go to Tools (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> in IE9) → "Manage add-ons"
2. Select "Search Providers" on the left
3. Check the "Prevent programs from suggesting changes to my default search provider" checkbox
4. Click **Close**

Source: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/Windows7/How-do-I-prevent-programs-from-changing-my-default-search-provider

---

#### Firefox:

Install the [BrowserProtect add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/browserprotect), which can detect and alert about changes to several configuration settings, including the default search engine.

Source: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/822455

---

#### Google Chrome:

Dev versions of Chrome, as well as Chromium, should have a feature called *Protector*, which you can activate by appending `-Protector` to the Target field of your Chrome shortcut. After that, Chrome should warn you about any changes to your default search engine.

I'm not sure if this is available in the stable release, though.

Source: http://techdows.com/2011/12/google-chrome-prevents-defualt-search-engine-changes-by-malware.html

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Do you know if other browsers have that option?

Comment: There's an add-on available for Firefox, see my updated answer. I haven't found anything for Opera or Chrome yet, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Opera is my daily browser but it's rarely targeted with this stuff, one benefit of using an underdog. The Firefox add-on is perfect though. Thanks for that. Although if you somehow find solutions for all browsers I bet plenty of other people would find it useful too.

Comment: Found a possible solution for Chrome (see updated answer), but nothing for Opera yet.

Comment: I have no idea how to test this -Protector flag ... Know of anything I can try?

Comment: @VianEsterhuizen Just right-click on your Chrome shortcut and select Properties, then in the Target field add a space and the `-Protector` flag.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5949/discussion-between-vian-esterhuizen-and-indrek)

Comment: The extension has since been removed :(